# Determine if two lists contain the same distinct items

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have two lists of strings

```
val list1 = listOf("aPPLES", "bANANA", "cARROTs")
val list2 = listOf("cARROTs", "bANANA", "aPPLES")
```

- Order could be different
- in some scenarios one of the list could be empty.
- both lists could be empty

I could do a simple checking of the size and then check `containsAll` to see if the strings match. Was wondering if there is a one liner in kotlin for collections .

Comment: Err... `list1 == list2`?

Comment: “_Order could be different_” — Do you want the lists to compare as equal in that case?  (And if so, is a list really the right data structure, or would a set be more appropriate?)

Comment: Ahh, I totally missed "order" part.

Comment: And what about if there are duplicate items?

Comment: I agree set is better suited for this

Answer (score 2):

You should use set, not list:

```
setOf("aPPLES", "bANANA", "cARROTs") == setOf("cARROTs", "bANANA", "aPPLES")
```

Comment: This approach conveys the intent very cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort both the lists using `.sort()` and use the `==` operator.